# react router not updating browser's location bar

Tags: react-router

I met a weird problem here, I am using a simple router set up like:

```
<Provider store={store}>
<div>
  <Router
    location='history'
    history={createHistory({queryKey: false})}
    onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
      <Route path="/" component={Main}>
        <Route path="datacenter/:name" component={App} />
        <Route path="operation" component={OperationComponent} />
      </Route>
  </Router>
  <DevTools />
</div>
</Provider>
```

and I have a nav list that manipulates the History:

```
<SelectableList subheader='OPERATIONS' valueLink={{value: this.props.location.pathname, requestChange: this.operationChanged}}>
        <ListItem primaryText='Checks' value='/operation' onTouchTap={this.handleClose}/>
      </SelectableList>
```

with action callback:

```
operationChanged = (evt, val) => {
this.props.history.push(val);
};
```

the problem is the navigation is working, when I click one of the list item, I am navigated to the path as expected, however, the selected path is not being updated to browser's address bar ...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE *********

Turns out, it is an issue related to webpack-dev-server, while using this dev tool, the react-router failed to update browser's location bar ... did not figure out why though

Comment: Oooh, great find with webpack-dev-server.  I *think* what's going on is that webpack-dev-server renders everything inside of an iframe.  So when you push a history state, it updates the URL of that iframe, not the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because on the Router you are setting:

```
location='history'
```

Try removing that line, also a JSBin or plnkr would be helpful so I could play around with it!

check out the docs here and follow the basic setup:  [Check out the bottom of the second example!](https://github.com/rackt/react-router)

Comment: I tried initially without the `location='history'` line and it was not working